# Sharing variables in python

Tags: python, variables, config

So I've recently been working on a simple project, and I've used "Jaheim Archibald's Login System" for logging in to my thing. I've found a variable that is the username entered, and I want to share that variable across another script that I'm creating. I've tried using the 'config' module, but it just gives me an attribute error.

EDIT:

Here is the sharing I tried to do:

Loginregister.py:

```
import config

config.x = userName
```

Account.py:

```
import config
print(config.x)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Account.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(config.x)
AttributeError: module 'config' has no attribute 'x'
```

Comment: Please [edit] to include a [mcve] with code for what you've tried so far and the full error traceback so that we can understand how to help

Comment: We're going to need a bit more info here.  What is this "login system" you are using?  What do you mean by "share?  How are you running your script and the other script?  What did you try with the `config` module?

Comment: Sorry, Sorry I'm gonna edit this question to make this more specific.

Comment: Ah this mistake seems logical. I voted to reopen and can explain in more detail in an answer once reopened, but briefly: `import` might be a misnomer because it evokes imagery of a single object `config` being shared between multiple modules. This is not the case, and instead it creates a DIFFERENT `config` object in each individual module. Setting `config.x` in Loginregister, therefore, does not affect the `config` object in Account.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to overview this answer more thoroughly to fix my problem :)

Comment: So you are saying that python thinks that config is just a plain module and I am trying to get an attribute from it?